# Extract custom source code attributes with Clang Tool

Tags: clang++

I am developing a tool that parses and type checks code using clang and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get non-standard clang attributes from the source code. For example, I'd like to annotate a loop with a loop invariant or an expression with `[[not_null]]`. Is this possible? Maybe there is some option that would say

Here's a concrete example:

```cpp
struct custom { };
int test() {
  int x;
  switch (1) {
  case 1:
    x = 1;
    [[fallthrough]] ;
  case 2:
    x = 2;
    break;
  }
  [[custom()]]
  if (1) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
}
```

The resulting AST looks like this:

```
`-FunctionDecl 0x55a9780ebba0 <line:2:1, line:14:1> line:2:5 test 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x55a9780ec060 <col:12, line:14:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x55a9780ebd08 <line:3:3, col:8>
    | `-VarDecl 0x55a9780ebca0 <col:3, col:7> col:7 used x 'int'
    |-SwitchStmt 0x55a9780ebd40 <line:4:3, line:11:3>
    | |-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebd20 <line:4:11> 'int' 1
    | `-CompoundStmt 0x55a9780ebf40 <col:14, line:11:3>
    |   |-CaseStmt 0x55a9780ebda0 <line:5:3, line:6:9>
    |   | |-ConstantExpr 0x55a9780ebd80 <line:5:8> 'int' Int: 1
    |   | | `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebd60 <col:8> 'int' 1
    |   | `-BinaryOperator 0x55a9780ebe08 <line:6:5, col:9> 'int' lvalue '='
    |   |   |-DeclRefExpr 0x55a9780ebdc8 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x55a9780ebca0 'x' 'int'
    |   |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebde8 <col:9> 'int' 1
    |   |-AttributedStmt 0x55a9780ebe58 <line:7:5, col:21>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< GOT Fallthrough
    |   | |-FallThroughAttr 0x55a9780ebe30 <col:7>
    |   | `-NullStmt 0x55a9780ebe28 <col:21>
    |   |-CaseStmt 0x55a9780ebeb0 <line:8:3, line:9:9>
    |   | |-ConstantExpr 0x55a9780ebe90 <line:8:8> 'int' Int: 2
    |   | | `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebe70 <col:8> 'int' 2
    |   | `-BinaryOperator 0x55a9780ebf18 <line:9:5, col:9> 'int' lvalue '='
    |   |   |-DeclRefExpr 0x55a9780ebed8 <col:5> 'int' lvalue Var 0x55a9780ebca0 'x' 'int'
    |   |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebef8 <col:9> 'int' 2
    |   `-BreakStmt 0x55a9780ebf38 <line:10:5>
    `-IfStmt 0x55a9780ec038 <line:13:3, col:41> has_else  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MISSING custom
      |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x55a9780ebf90 <col:7> 'bool' <IntegralToBoolean>
      | `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebf70 <col:7> 'int' 1
      |-CompoundStmt 0x55a9780ebfd8 <col:10, col:22>
      | `-ReturnStmt 0x55a9780ebfc8 <col:12, col:19>
      |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebfa8 <col:19> 'int' 1
      `-CompoundStmt 0x55a9780ec020 <col:29, col:41>
        `-ReturnStmt 0x55a9780ec010 <col:31, col:38>
          `-IntegerLiteral 0x55a9780ebff0 <col:38> 'int' 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. there are two ways AFAIK.

First is to add your new definition to Clang. You can modify Clang source in `tools/clang/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td`. Then Clang knows your new attribute. Cons could be you need to rebuild your entire source code every time for a change.

Second is to use an available attribute `annotate`. For example `[[clang::annotate("not_null")]]`. I personally prefer the flexibility of this approach.

Here is a MWE assume i want to search a function decl with a custom attribute:

```
#define MY_ATTR [[clang::annotate("my_attr")]]

...

// i want to extract this attribute
MY_ATTR void foo(...) { ... }
```

i can implement a visitor function like:

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *D) {                                                                                                                                                                                 
   if (D->hasAttrs()) {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     for (auto attr : D->getAttrs()) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
       std::string attr_name(attr->getSpelling());                                                                                                                                                                                  
       std::string attr_annotate("annotate");                                                                                                                                                                                       
       std::string attr_my("annotate(\"my_attr\")");                                                                                                                                                                     
       if (attr_name == attr_annotate) {                                                                                                                                                                                            
         std::string SS; llvm::raw_string_ostream S(SS);                                                                                                                                                                            
         attr->printPretty(S, Policy);                                                                                                                                                                                              
         std::string attr_string(S.str());                                                                                                                                                                                          
         if (attr_string.find(attr_my) != std::string::npos) { 
           // found it! do stuff here!
           // ...
         }
       }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   }
  return true;
}
```

i think you can easily adapt it to your loop annotation.

Comment: Thanks! From looking through the docs, it looks like I basically need to implement my own parser for the annotation. In the above you are asking clang to prettyPrint it, is there any way to get at the representation that it is pretty printing from?

Comment: yes, you need to implement your own parser. Extract strings like in the answer is just one possibility that worked for me. Look into [clang::Attr](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Attr.html) reference, i dont know how to distinguish two `clang::annotate` attributes with different annotations. That is why i pretty print the strings and compare the strings in the parser.